# How can i get started VR Video Development?(editing vr videos)

Tags: virtual-reality, video-editing

I want to make simple app that edit my virtual reality videos.How can i get started? I have some programming knowledge (C#, C++,Unity) I am looking for basic editing operations.For example changing background of the video,cropping video.
i did some research on Google but I have lots of questions in my mind.
What languages should I use?What SDK should I use?How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get into this is to make a [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) wrapper. It might not be the fastest API and will require lots of hacks to get around, but there is a reason why it's embedded in so many video editing utilities: it works.

You can go via two routes, the API or using the executable and piping in/out of it (C#'s `System.Diagnostics.Process` with pipes will work well). If you know shell concepts well, I'd suggest starting with the second one.

Word of advice, standalone operations will be easy with FFmpeg, but combining many of them is hard and often requires multiple passes with temporary files.

Edit: oh and about VR, it doesn't matter at this level. It would if you were to be stitching the video or making (but not applying) overlays.